# Using non clustered index for efficient searching

Tags: sql-server, indexing, sqlperformance, non-clustered-index

I have created non clustered index on combination of three columns. Do I need to specify all the three columns in where condition to used non clustered index.

Comment: I don't think so. But in order for that index to be used, the first column must be in the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to utilize your index you have to use like this.

Index: Ix_threecols(c1,c2,c3)

```
1. select c1,c2,c3 from table where c1=val
and c2=val and c3=val
2. select c1,c2,c3 from table where c1=val
and c2=val
3. select c1,c2,c3 from table where c1=val
```

Your left most first column in the index should be used in the where clause.
Please don't use (*) in your select since it may lead to index scan.

We have to check the execution plan for more analysis on this.

Comment: what if i use where c1=val or c2 =val

Comment: You can use like this but it would be an index scan if you use 'or'

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no.

If at least the first column in the index appears in your `where` clause, the index **can** be used.
Whether or not it **will** be used is already up to the optimizer, but assuming you don't have any other indexes on other columns in the `where` clause, it will probably be used.